# Xcode 4 Applescript to build and run the current target app

Tags: applescript, xcode4

I'm looking for some applescript that would tell Xcode to run the current target.

I'd like to automate Xcode from textmate to provide "Run in simulator" and "Run on device".

This is as far as I got:

```
tell application "Xcode"
  set myWorkspace to active workspace document
  set myProject to the active project document of myWorkspace  -- Can’t get active project document of workspace document "project.xcworkspace"
  ...
end tell
```

Comment: I don't have a proper solution for you (beyond the standard approach of clicking menu items), but your first error is that you mean "set myProject to the first project of myWorkspace" in the third line. But I don't think you need to do that. Everything you want seems to be on the workspace document itself (except for the ability to run....)

Answer (score 0):

Creative use of the **xcodebuild** command line tool would very likely get you  much further.